# Документирование react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, документация

Наступило время для документации кода.
Поскольку проект для меня в совершенно новой области и относится к моему не любимому (мое субъективное мнение) `javascript` и, который включает функциональные компоненты `React`, собственно вопрос:
как документируются компоненты `React` (если это важно, то они абсолютно все функциональные), в том числе те, которые содержат вложенные компоненты? На что можно абслоютно честно не обращать внимания?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое главное - документировать логику (бизнес-логику). Это необходимо сделать в первую очередь. Как конкретно это сделать зависит от команды - как Вам будет удобнее. Попробуйте посмотреть в документациях и выберите наиболее подходящий для себя вариант.

Если Ваш проект стал очень большим, что стало пора выносить компоненты в отдельную библиотеку, то можно и данную библиотеку задокументировать. Лично я предпочитаю [React Styleguidist](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/). Но он не для React Native, а для React. Однако и для React Native существуют альтернативы.

Answer (score 1):

Что такое компонента. Компонента это - объект React. Значит и документировать его нужно как объект. Красивый комментарий это когда у тебя подписана функция, что она делает, и что возвращает. И зачем она вообще нужна. Подписан непонятнейший **участок кода**, и в плохой ситуации TODO, что реально надо сделать (лучше конечно использовать issue tracker). Не стоит подписывать участки кода а-ля "увеличивает счётчик на 1".

На вопрос как подписывать - лучше всего использовать @JSDoc https://jsdoc.app/
Его поддерживают 95% хороших IDE, и программисту легко будет понять и переиспользовать твой код по @JSDoc Search.

И не в коем случае не использовать переменные с короткими именами! Если запрос к сайту называется "request" то использовать полное слово "request" (не "req","reqst", и.т.д.) хороший код должен в первую очередь легко читаться как книга.

Так-же с именами функций/компонент/контроллеров к примеру компонента BlogPost должна и называться как BlogPostComponent, BlogPostPreviewComponent и.т.д. А не просто Post в папке blog/Post.jsx и blog/preview/Post.jsx

Красиво и главное понятно когда:

```
src/controllers/BlogController.jsx
src/components/BlogPostComponent.jsx
```

По поводу самого кода, очень советую переходить поскорее на TypeScript и подключить ESLint в режиме хотя-бы "standart" - это исправит кучу багов ещё на моменте разработки. У нас практический все проекты не залить на git если линтер не проверит код (githooks).